# How to insert a line in file in linux

Tags: linux, sed

I need to insert a line at line number 3 in file.txt. For this I am using `sed`. I need to insert below text in file:

```
Location=\home\user\Files\myfile.txt
```

To insert above line, I am doing:

```
sudo sed -i '3iLocation=\home\user\Files\myfile.txt' file.txt
```

This command is running but the text inserted is :

`Location=homeuserFilesmyfile.txt`

Why is this happening. How can I also include `\`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape a backslash `\` to interpret it literally.

To append the line without linebreak:

```
sed -i '3 s/$/Location=\\home\\user\\Files\\myfile.txt/' file.txt
```

- `$` - regex anchor, points to the end of the string

---

To insert specific line ***before*** the 3rd line:

```
sed -i '3iLocation=\\home\\user\\Files\\myfile.txt/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use escape character '\'.

sed -i '3iLocation=\home\user\Files\roamingfile.txt' file.txt

Comment: Facing an issue. I am inserting `/\home/\rony\`. When inserted it shows `\home\^Mahul\file.txt` because for `rony` it is considering `\r` as next line element. How to do this.?